# React - Styled Component with multiple classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend, styled-components

I'm about to build a small project in react using styled component, however, I have a question for using this package. I would like to create a styled component that brings together several classes but I don't know how to do, for example :

```
<div class="search-input search-input-small">
```

How to turn it into a styled component ? In css there are two different classes, but in styled component i don't know.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you need to think about the combined styles of both classes, and use props to adjust your styling dynamically. What do these classes do in normal CSS?

Comment: we can get @Aib Codes Daily example,

`.search-input {
background-color: blue;
}

.search-input-small {
color: white;

}`

Comment: First define `const SearchInput = styled.div\` backgroundColor: blue;\`` and then define `const SearchInputSmall= styled(SearchInput)\` color: white;\`` and use the  `SearchInputSmall` styled component in place of the div with multiple classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. For example, you could run with the base styling on a styled component and then "upgrade that with the additional styling.

```
const Div = styled.div`
     /// styles for className -> search-input
    }`
const SmallDiv = styled(Div)`
    /// styles for className -> search-input-small
   `
```

Also, if you know SASS you can structure your CSS with nesting using &. e.g.

```
 const Div = styled.div`
     .search-input {
          //CSS
          &-small {
             //CSS
           }
         
         }
     `
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer, but how to do if i've another div which use `.search-input-small` with another class like `hello-world search-input-small` ? Do I have to duplicate the css again and again ?

Comment: You can add all the classes you want to the Div and then apply the ones you are looking to utilize in a particular Div usage with the className keyword.

Answer (score 1):

With styled-components, you can go with a similar format.

Here we are creating a styled component named `Div`, within the styled component I've declared classes `.search-input` and `.search-input.search-input-small` to style the div from your example.

The `Div` is being treated as a parent container.

```
const Div = styled.div`

display: flex;
background-color: black; 

.search-input {
background-color: blue;
}
.search-input.search-input-small {
color: white;

}
`;
```

We call the newly created styled component like this:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
      <Div>
      <div className="search-input search-input-small">Hello</div>
      </Div>
  
  );
}
```

As you can see the `<div class="search-input search-input-small">` from your example is a child to the parent `Div`. The parent Div does not require styles but I have included them for this example.

Also here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-yonath-ib7n4?file=/src/App.js) with a working example.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer, but i've want to remove all of my html to use styled component, how to do that ? Thank you Aib !